# Syntax Error with MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to send this function in php but it keeps coming back with this error.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''tolu)' at line 2

```
function getDuplicate($case, $select,$from,$where,$equals,$and="",$equals2=""){

global $database_conndb;
global $conndb;

switch($case){
      case 1:
      $sql= "SELECT {$select} FROM {$from} WHERE {$where}='{$equals}'";
      break;
      case 2:
      $sql= "SELECT {$select} FROM {$from} WHERE {$where}='{$equals}' AND {$and} != '{$equals2}'";
      break;
      }
```

Comment: How are you calling this function?

Comment: Can you print out the actual SQL generated when you call the function?

Comment: Indeed, show us the actual print of one example.

Comment: `near ''tolu)` Looks to me like you have unescaped variables being passed into your query...

Comment: i am callng it using this function

Comment: //if the record isnt empty,put it in the record
   if($_POST['name'] !="" && getDuplicate(1,'name','categories','name',$name))
   {
    array_push($missing,'duplicate');
   }

Comment: This is the function below  if($_POST['name'] !="" && getDuplicate(1,'name','categories','name',$name))
   {
    array_push($missing,'duplicate');
   }

Comment: @burantashi2007 We're less concerned about the function call. We need to see what the value of the variable `$sql` is.  `echo $sql;`

Comment: Sorry for the delay this is the echo sql

Comment: <pre><code> echo isset($valid_name) ? $valid_name : NULL;
   echo isset($valid_duplicate) ? $valid_duplicate :NULL;

Answer (score 0):

looks like you did not escape the parameters correctly. look at this function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that there is an error in SQL statement then echo the SQL then copy it and execute that query manually into database. U will got the actual error occurence point.

Hope this why u will fix your bug